# How are the typescript definition files written in definitelyTyped?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

Are all the definition typescript files typed or is there a script automating the writing by reading the documentation of the particular library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, I do not believe you can generate them from documentation. Well, I am sure people have tried and been successful and there are open source attempts such as [this](https://github.com/englercj/tsd-jsdoc) but generally speaking, they need to be manually maintained on a per project basis.

Another reason for saying this is because I have made several definition files and the documentation is just never enough.  In both Phaser and Pixi libraries, there are a lot of added interfaces, and many "fixes" which cannot be picked up via documentation and do require specific treatment by a human.